# How to use vhosts to redirect users to another domain

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, virtualhost

A web site that we host recently changed it's domain name from www.domainA.com to www.domainB.com

My vhost file originally looked like this:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domainA.com
        ServerAlias domainA.com
        DocumentRoot /sites/DomainA/webroot
    </VirtualHost>
```

In the vhost file I added an alias that shows the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domainA.com
    ServerAlias domainA.com
    ServerAlias www.domainB.com
    ServerAlias domainB.com
    DocumentRoot /sites/DomainA/webroot
</VirtualHost>
```

This resulted in users who go to DomainB.com being shown the site with the links all showing  domainB.com

When a user goes to the site from www.DomainA.com they see www.DomainA.com in the browser bar, before they click on a link, and then they see www.DomainB.com in the browser bar

I would like all visitors to the old domain to be instantly redirected to new domain, and I am considering my options to do so.

what would I need to add to the vhost to make sure the users always see the new domain name in their browser bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a separate VirtualHost for the old domain, and put redirect there.

The config would look something like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domainA.com
    ServerAlias domainA.com
    Redirect 301 / http://www.domainB.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

And then you would remove the ServerAliases for this domain in the other VirtualHost configuration.

Comment: I'm assuming that if I add an access log file to this vhost, then I can log all attempts to hit the old domain? If so, then I have a perfect solution for what I want to do.

Comment: Yes, you can have per-vhost access logs.